# Python module for parsing cusomized config files

Tags: python

I have a config file like this:

asaasdfg fdhshs "kgk jjjd" jdyesgs
gdgdg urur "irit jhd *" djjdj
trteyuueu ueue "jyuoro" ooyoy

and so on. I am able to parse it using  my own parser module (using regex) but that assumes a strict structure for the file (e.g. elements in each row separated by a single whitespace). Is there a general python module for parsing such files so that it won't matter how many whitespaces separate the elements.

I have looked at [this](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/configparser.html#customizing-parser-behaviour) but it assumes a different file structure than what I have. In particular, I don't have sections or key:value pairs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why use a custom format? Use JSON for configs humans won't edit, and either INI (with ConfigParser) or YAML for those humans will edit.

Comment: well I am given the config files and I'm not the one creating them.

Comment: a combination of the CSV module and namedtuple is one option. The CSV module supports several options to handle quoted strings.

Comment: @Colin, or you could just use straight Python like Django does. Since there is no need to recompile Python code, there really isn't a compelling reason to store your config in a different format like you would with Java or C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it's not completely clear what you need, the `shlex` module will happily parse things like quoted strings in ways that generally make sense.  For example, given your sample input, the following code:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    parts = shlex.split(line)
    print parts
```

Will produce:

```
['asaasdfg', 'fdhshs', 'kgk jjjd', 'jdyesgs']
['gdgdg', 'urur', 'irit jhd *', 'djjdj']
['trteyuueu', 'ueue', 'jyuoro', 'ooyoy']
```